# Only getting last element of Group element text when ReadingXML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am tryin to read an XML file but when I read it in it's only picking up on the last value of my Group element instead of setting the text property of the Group at the endelement break for each Group. All help is appreciated.

```
public static void ReadFile()
{
    string MyText = string.Empty;
    string Notes = string.Empty;
    string UserName = string.Empty;
    string Password = string.Empty;
    string Url = string.Empty;
    string Title = string.Empty;
    string MyGroup = string.Empty;

    Group group = new Group("Hello", 0);

    XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader("C:/KeyText.xml");
    while (xmlReader.Read()) // Read nodes sequentially
    {
        if (xmlReader.Name == "Group" & xmlReader.NodeType.ToString() == "EndElement")
        {
            group.Text = MyText;
            AddGroupXML(group);
        }

        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (xmlReader.LocalName == "Text")
            {
                MyText = xmlReader.ReadString();
            }

            if (xmlReader.LocalName == "Notes")
            {
                Notes = xmlReader.ReadString();
            }

            if (xmlReader.LocalName == "UserName")
            {
                UserName = xmlReader.ReadString();
            }

            if (xmlReader.LocalName == "Password")
            {
                Password = xmlReader.ReadString();
            }

            if (xmlReader.LocalName == "Url")
            {
                Url = xmlReader.ReadString();
            }

            if (xmlReader.LocalName == "Title")
            {
                Title = xmlReader.ReadString();
            }
        }

        if (xmlReader.Name == "Key" & xmlReader.NodeType.ToString() == "EndElement")
        {
            Key MyKey = new Key();
            MyKey.Notes = Notes;
            MyKey.Title = Title;
            MyKey.UserName = UserName;
            MyKey.Url = Url;
            MyKey.Password = Password;

            group.Keys.Add(MyKey);
        }
    }

    xmlReader.Close();
    GroupsRead.Invoke();
}
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Groups>
  <Group>
    <ImageIndex>0</ImageIndex>
    <Text>wcwpgcuotlx</Text>
    <Keys>
      <Dog/>
      <Key>
        <Notes>4ktaiyduner</Notes>
        <Password>0y2cg1kodre</Password>
        <Title>a2yj4biqd5u</Title>
        <Url>de2uym5vyg1</Url>
        <UserName>ogcl3uyvy2r</UserName>
      </Key>
      <Key>
        <Notes>3dmchyaqcvt</Notes>
        <Password>lbgfralkng4</Password>
        <Title>fnha4ienzua</Title>
        <Url>n3pmk5elaso</Url>
        <UserName>njk55ov4eef</UserName>
      </Key>
    </Keys>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <ImageIndex>0</ImageIndex>
    <Text>vrmijzokft2</Text>
    <Keys>
      <Dog/>
    </Keys>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

Comment: Not every Group contains the Key element but they all contain the Group element. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine, it enters 2 times in AddGroupXML with the correct Text property set

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: if (xmlReader.Name == "Group" & xmlReader.NodeType.ToString() == "EndElement")
                {


                    Group group = New Group(MyText,0);


                    AddGroupXML(group);
                     
                   }

Comment: When I use the new Group in the if statement it seems to read correctly to get text for both groups...but I have no way of adding keys because of scope issues with new Group being declared in the if statement.                                                                                                                             if (xmlReader.Name == "Group" & xmlReader.NodeType.ToString() == "EndElement")
                {

                    Group group = New Group(MyText,0);


                    AddGroupXML(group);
                     
                   }

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have one `Group` object that you use for all groups. So, since you call `AddGroupXML()` with the same argument every time, the result will contain the same object several times. And the text value will be the last you set for it.

To fix this, change the code that adds the group to something like:

```
group.Text = MyText;
AddGroupXML(group);
group = new Group("Hello", 0);
```

In the future, it might be easier if you used LINQ to XML to process the XML. Your code would be much simpler if you used that. (The disadvantage of that approach is that it loads the whole XML into memory, which is a bad idea for huge XML files.)

Comment: That seems to be what it was. Thanks alot. It would be nice to sleep again. It does seem that LINQ is a good alternative. Wish I wasn't such a linear thinker.